# “What does it matter if I lie to you, my love ?”

Tags: grammaire, sens, accord, indications-de-lieu

How would one render this statement into French ?

> What does it matter if I lie to you ?

My attempt would be: “A-t-il importance si je te mens, chérie ?”

Comment: Why would you lie to your love...?

Answer (score 8):

You can say :

> Quelle importance si je te/vous mens, mon amour ?

or

> Qu'importe si je te/vous mens, mon amour ?

Comment: "Est-ce important si je te/vous mens ?" or "cela at-t-il de l'importance si je/vous mens ?" would be right too but your translation is better.

Comment: Pourquoi avez-vous supprimé *, mon amour* qui supprimerait l'option */vous* ?

Comment: @cl-r "mon amour" est présent dans le titre, mais pas dans la question, il y a donc confusion :)

Comment: @Random ... certainement, mais Spencer l'a traduit par *chérie* , et peu de personnes vouvoient (voussoient) l'élu de leur cœur :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with

> Quelle importance que je te/vous mente, mon amour ?

"importe + si" feels awkward imho

Comment: .... to me, this feels even MORE awkward than importe + si, very honestly.

Answer (score 0):

Plus courant / more current

> Chérie, qu'est-ce que ça peut faire si je te mens ?

or to emphasize on irrelevance :

> Chérie, qu'est-ce que ça peut bien faire si je te mens ?